# Magento error ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS, when sorting products

Tags: magento-1.9, sorting

Some days ago I noticed a redirect loop on a Magento 1.9.2.4 installation I'm working on.

The issue is visible when ordering products in the front end, I can't say when it started.

You can take a look at the problem here: https://www.kirpalani.com/en/sale

If you order by any option you get stuck in an infinite redirect loop, for example, price: https://www.kirpalani.com/en/sale?dir=asc&order=price

I tried anything I could think of, including:

clear magento cache
clear browser cache
clear cookies
reindex rewrite rules
reset files permissions
checking db for corrupted tables
restoring db from a backup
...
I'm stuck on this issue for 4 days now and I don't have any other idea how to solve this. Any thought? Is there something trivial I'm missing?

PHP logs are clear, I'm running PHP 5.5 FPM with nginx on centos 7.

1. error ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS
2. Blog post : permission issue
3. Magento sort Categories & subcategory by Name when Display on Site ( multiple language site )

Thanks in advance.

Comment: it looks like for one query it works fine but for more than one query it redirect recursively.

Comment: I have this exact problem! When sorting on a category page the page just redirects forever, but only if two get variables are present. How did you fix it?

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue on Magento 1.9.1.0 and only just discovered it.

It turns out this bug was introduced with the 8788 Patch but only seems to affect some builds.

To resolve go to file: app/code/core/Mage/Core/Helper/Url.php

On line 54:

Replace

```
return $this->escapeUrl($url);
```

with

```
return $url;
```